# How do I add permission for Geolocator in Android?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, geolocation

So I have the following error:

```
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
D/FlutterLocationService( 6191): Creating service.
D/FlutterLocationService( 6191): Binding to location service.
Lost connection to device.
```

I also don't know why it says **D/FlutterLocationService**, instead of **D/FlutterGeolocator**.

I heard you now need to manually ask for permission, but have zero clue how to do that. How should I add the code for Geolocator permissions to this code?

```
AppStateProvider() {
_saveDeviceToken();
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage;
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp;

_setCustomMapPin();
_getUserLocation();
_listemToDrivers();
Geolocator.getPositionStream().listen(_updatePosition);


}

// ANCHOR: MAPS & LOCATION METHODS
  _updatePosition(Position newPosition) {
    position = newPosition;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<Position> _getUserLocation() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
    List<Placemark> placemark =
        await placemarkFromCoordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude);
```

Answer (score 0):

you simply add permission request before you get user location
so inside the _getUserLocation() and before

```
position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
```

add below code.

```
final permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
  if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
    permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      // Permissions are denied, next time you could try
      // requesting permissions again (this is also where
      // Android's shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale 
      // returned true. According to Android guidelines
      // your App should show an explanatory UI now.
      return Future.error('Location permissions are denied');
    }
  }
if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
    // Permissions are denied forever, handle appropriately. 
    return Future.error(
      'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.');
  }
```

And you can probably check https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator as well